# Maven: print out "reactor summary" every time.

Tags: maven

How can I get Maven to print out the "reactor summary" every time after the build? Currently, it only prints during a build break.

Comment: Can you give an example and more information about your setup?

Comment: With Maven 3.2.1 here the Reactor Summary is printed at the end of a successful build, too.